# Download Manager gives error code 16 with rn-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

download manager gives error code 16 with rn-fetch-blob. If I use the android download manager. If I don't, use the android download manager, then the app crashes.

android version: 11.

Code:

```
let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
RNFetchBlob
.config({
  addAndroidDownloads : {
    useDownloadManager : true,
    notification : true,
    mime : 'image/*',
    mediaScannable : true,
    description : 'File downloaded by download manager.',
    path : dirs.DownloadDir + '/' + fileName,
    overwrite: true,
    fileCache: true,
  },
})
.fetch('GET', FILE_URL, {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
})
.then((res) => {
  console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
})
```

Following are set in manifest.xml:

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Please if anyone can provide me with a solution.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @paresh borana - any update. Facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

According to their [readme](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob), you need to add the DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE  action when using the download manager.

```
Also, if you're going to use Android Download Manager you have to add this to AndroidManifest.xml

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
+           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Also, I've been facing the error code 16 when the Authentication header was missing for a call that needed one.