# React Native download manager fails with status code 16 when downloading on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I have been trying to fix an issue with downloading a `zip` file from our service on our `Android` app. The `iOS` works fine, but on `Android` I get the following error:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:149 Error downloading file Error: Download manager failed to download from  <download_urll> Status Code = 16
```

My download code looks like this. We are using `react-native-blob-util`:

```
    const FILE_URL = uri;

    const { config, fs } = ReactNativeBlobUtil;
    const { dirs } = fs;
    let writePath = dirs.DocumentDir;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      writePath = `${dirs.DownloadDir.split('Android')[0]}Download`;
    }

    const options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        path: writePath + '/' + fileName + '.' + fileExtension,
        description: `Downloading ${fileName}{}`,
        notification: true,
        useDownloadManager: true,
      },
    };

    return await config(options)
      .fetch('GET', FILE_URL, {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
      })
      .then(() => {
        // Handle download success
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // Handle download failure
      });
```

I have tried pretty much everything I found on the answers [here](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/167), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794169/download-manager-gives-error-code-16-with-rn-fetch-blob), [here](https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-rnfetchblob-error-download-manager-failed-to-download-from-url.375985/) and even [here](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/640). And also several other places I found. I have checked the authentication too. It's not that.

Any idea what this might be? The issue is that this seems to occur only in the production variant of our `Android` app, and works just fine on the rest, including the production variant of our `iOS` app. A real head scratcher.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: i'm getting the same issue, but i need to send API + authentication token + body